# Hide Floating Action Button (FAB) on recyclerview click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I'm trying to hide my floating action button when a user clicks on an item in the recyclerview but nothing happens using the code below in my main activity class. Using the onscrolled method to hide my FAB upon scrolling, presented no issues in hiding the fab. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
val mFab2 = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton2)
val mRecyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.s_list)


fun hideFabWhenRecClicked(fab2: FloatingActionButton,recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v:View) {
            fab2.hide()
        }
    })
}

hideFabWhenRecClicked(mFab2,mRecyclerView)
```

Comment: please show whole file maybe you never call the function

Comment: I do call the function using hideFabWhenRecClicked(mFab2,mRecyclerView) but it doesn't get called...while my onscroll function hideFabWhenScroll(mFab2,mRecyclerView) does get called.  Also there is too much code to decypher that would not be helpful in my MainActivity to post.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
val mFab2 = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton2)
val mRecyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.s_list)


fun hideFabWhenRecClicked(fab2: FloatingActionButton,recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v:View) {
            fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    })
}


hideFabWhenRecClicked(mFab2,mRecyclerView)
```

I hope to be useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using onResume function instead:

`override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        fab2.hide()
}`